# How can I find the height & width of a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm developing iPhone app. In that I have to save textview content as image in photo album. I tried to capture the screen but it captured only the visible part of the textview. So I decided to save using textview height and width. Could any one please help me?

Comment: I think there's too much wrong with this question to salvage it.  It seems that what she **really** wants is to draw the text from a UITextView into a UIImage and save it to a file, not just find the dimensions of a UITextView.  It's completely unclear without correction though.

Comment: Im developing one project.in tat i hav to create ascii art for a given image.im genrating tat art in textview.now i hav to store tat content in photo album.Is tis possible to save it as image?could u please help me

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `frame` property?

```
self.textview.frame.size.width
self.textview.frame.size.height
```

Comment: ya thanks a lot.its working.could u pls help me to save textview content into photo gallery.im using the code as follows,       //Save image
-(IBAction)captureScreen:(id)sender
{ 
    CGRect contextRect  = CGRectMake(0,0,335,373);// whatever you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size); 
    
    [resultTextView_.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);[viewsave setHidden:YES];
}

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog("Height : %f Width : %f",textview.frame.size.width,textview.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: ya thanks a lot.its working.could u pls help me to save textview content into photo gallery.im using the code as follows, //Save image -(IBAction)captureScreen:(id)sender { CGRect contextRect = CGRectMake(0,0,335,373);// whatever you need UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size); [resultTextView_.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);[viewsave setHidden:YES]; }

Comment: could u please help me to save textview content as image in photo album

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is save the textview layer to a UIImage

Comment: actually im developing app to generate ascii art for an image.i generate such ascii art in textview.now i hav to save tat ascii art into photo album.

Comment: could u pls help me to save textview content into photo gallery